Spark re computes the cached Dataframes
Working on a Spark application written in Scala. Have six functions. Each function takes two Dataframes as an input, processes them and emits one result DF. I am caching the result of each function's DF and invoking count on them to materialize the same. In the sixth function, I am using all the above five output DFs to perform a join operation. I am expecting Spark to use the cached the DFs to perform the join but it starts from function 1 to recompute all the necessary DFs (based on the query plan and DAG). Is this expected?
//functions 1 to 5 to generate joinedLeaseDF5
//Now after getting joinedLeaseDF5, caching it
joinedLeaseDF5.cache()
joinedLeaseDF5.count()


val joinedLeaseDF6 = joinedLeaseDF5
        .join(credDF,
          joinedLeaseDF5("cust_id") === credDF("cust_id"),
          "left_outer")

At this point, I could see all logic to compute joinedLeaseDF5 being executed.

what version of spark are you using?

The provided snippet looks okay, but it doesn't show how the joinedLeaseDF5 is constructed. Its going to be hard to conclude anything without that.
